# autonomous lawnmower with gps, radar and remote control

Tags: pi-3b+, home-automation

I am trying to build an autonomous lawnmower using raspberry pi 3B+. I want to include auto-steering or remote control and also I want to include the radar as well to avoid any obstacles and also want to include GPS to stay in its designated area.

I am completely new to this development, if anyone does this kind of things, please guide me on what parts I need and how to do it, I found some stuff online but they are very small DIY which won't work on the actual yard.

Comment: start with the small projects and work your way up

Answer (score 0):

Pretty cool project! 
I don't want to sound negative, but I think this is a pretty elaborate project and maybe not the best one to start with.

Nevertheless, here are some links that may give you some ideas:
https://hackaday.com/2017/03/01/where-are-the-autonomous-lawnmowers/
https://www.ardumower.de/index.php/en/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxsdHD1lHQ4